# Why does SQL Server's AND condition not work?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a simple but weird problem in SQL Server; these lines of code work correctly:

```
SELECT MAX(BPInfoID) 
FROM BasicPersonalInfo 
WHERE LastName LIKE N'ج%';

SELECT LEFT(Client.DocNum, 5) 
FROM Client 
WHERE Client.BPInfoID = (SELECT MAX(BPInfoID) 
                         FROM BasicPersonalInfo 
                         WHERE LastName LIKE N'ج%');

SELECT LEFT(Client.DocNum, 5) 
FROM Client 
WHERE Client.DocNumMood = 0;
```

screenshots:

[image]
[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHd1x.jpg

all table's records: https://i.stack.imgur.com/weSq9.jpg

BPInfoID - DocNumMood -  DocNum
35       - False      -     00001/ج/97
36      -  False      -     00002/ج/97
37      -  True     -   00003/ج/97
38    -    False    -       00001/ط/97

but when I combine them together, this query doesn't work and shows nothing

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(Client.DocNum, 5) 
FROM 
    Client 
WHERE 
    Client.DocNumMood = 0 
    AND Client.BPInfoID = (SELECT MAX(BPInfoID) 
                           FROM BasicPersonalInfo 
                           WHERE LastName LIKE N'ج%');
```

Do you know why?
Thanks

Comment: **SHOW US** some sample data that these queries return! Most likely, you just don't have any rows that match those two conditions at the same time ......

Comment: Do you have run the SELECT MAX as standallone? And then verified that the result is really available?

Comment: does those three queries return same record?

Comment: And in your second query, does *any* of the rows contain the value `37` (that gets selected from the `BasicPersonInfo` table) for its `BPInfoID`?? Unfortunately, this **crucial** info is **not** visible from your screenshots.... please run `SELECT LEFT(Client.DocNum, 5), BPInfoID FROM Client 
WHERE Client.DocNumMood = 0;` and post those results here - as **properly formatted TEXT**- not yet another screenshot!!

Comment: `Do you know why?` because such is your data. And the query. If you show us sample data and desired output suggestions could become more specific. And please don't share that info as **screenshot**.

Comment: It does "work" and nothing in your question makes me think otherwise.

Comment: i add screenshots and a link of last screenshot .. data has no problem

Comment: we don't want to see screen shot. Please show us in text please

Comment: @Squirrel ok i add them . i expect the result be 00002

Comment: @marc_s i update the question details . look at them pls .i want the max BPInfoID where DocNumMood=false and DocNum starts with ج

Comment: Your sample doesn't have most of the columns mentioned in the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably simply because the record that has the MAX(BPInfoID) for the BPInfoID doesn't have DocNumMood = 0

You can verify if the seperate queries return a record that's in both.

If the intent was to return those that's are in either of those seperate queries?  Then the AND in the WHERE could be replaced by an OR.

But based on the comments, you actually want to get the Client record with that maximum BPInfoID but only for those where DocNumMood is false.

Since BPInfoID is probably the primary key in BasicPersonalInfo.
Then Client can simply be joined to BasicPersonalInfo on that BPInfoID.

And then with a TOP 1 combined with the ORDER BY you can get your expected result.

```
SELECT TOP 1 LEFT(cl.DocNum, 5) As DocNumPart
FROM Client AS cl
JOIN BasicPersonalInfo info 
  ON (info.BPInfoID = cl.BPInfoID AND 
      info.LastName LIKE N'ج%')
WHERE cl.DocNumMood = 0
ORDER BY cl.BPInfoID DESC;
```

You'll find a test on SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c59ac/7/0)

Comment: i add screenshots

Comment: @mohamdJ.A.  00003 is in the 3th result but not in the second. That confirms my guess. But you haven't included an expected result yet. So what are you expecting for the result?

Comment: i expect this line `SELECT LEFT(Client.DocNum,5) FROM Client WHERE  BPInfoID=(SELECT MAX(BPInfoID) FROM BasicPersonalInfo WHERE LastName like N'ج%)' AND Client.DocNumMood = 0` return 00002 look at this image https://imgur.com/u9sZIZt

Comment: @mohamdJ.A. Ah right, I see, you want those max of the false.  Ok, I'll try to fiddle it a bit.

Comment: yes ,if you find out something tell me, i need it ,tnx

Comment: @mohamdJ.A.  The resulting SQL will look a bit different than what you probably expected. But I think it will work out for you. Btw, that arabic character is a pain to deal with in Notepad.

Comment: tnxxxx a lot , yes it works , i also solved it from another way `select top 1 LEFT(Client.DocNum,5)  from Client where DocNum like N'%ج%' and DocNumMood=0 order by BPInfoID desc` .. sorry if my question wan't clear at first .. thank u again for ur answer i like to use it cause it seems more professional